# Word Macro for Mail Merge export to PDF

Tags: vba, collections, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm running a macro in Word which worked fine before my last clean format.
The mail-merge word reads records from an Excel file.
It gives me a run-time error 5941 on the following line:

```vb
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDirectory & "\" & ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("company_name").Value & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

I don't know if a reference needs to be added to the Macro or what? Pls help.
Z

Comment: Is there supposed to be something between the quotes following `strDirectory`?

Comment: There is a backslash. but it doesn't show here ... idk why

Comment: Is the error message something like "The Requested Member of Collection Does Not Exist"? If that is the case either "company_name" isn't a valid datafield name or `ActiveDocument` is referring to a different document than the one that contains it.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. The datafield name is correct. How do I know which document is the ActiveDocument? I only have one word document opened and the associated XL table. I can browse throu all the records in the word document using the preview results arrows...

Comment: `ActiveDocument.name` just before that line. You can also iterate through the datafields and see if there is a match there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.mailmergedatasource

Comment: The line: MsgBox ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.Name gives me exactly the XL file I'm using to merge data into my Word macro-enabled document. I can confirm that the ActiveDocument is the intended data source file.